# Adding PJAX support to current Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, pjax

I have an existing website which uses standard Rails layouts. Clicking each link in the website currently loads and renders the relevant view.

Recently though, I've heard about PJAX and i'd like to convert the entire site to use it, what do I need to change - layout wise, in order to be able to utilise it?

Is there a guide which walks through this process which I may have missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Railscast's tutorial is great: http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax?autoplay=true